# ClaimsIdentity UserId contains UserName and the other way around

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, asp.net-identity

When using Identity in ASP.NET Core 5.0 with JWT bearer authentication (don't know if the latter is playing into this) I have the problem, that I can't get the user by using `userManager.GetUserAsync(Context.User)`. That is because when using it I get the exception stating `[...] is not valid value for Int32. (Parameter: 'value')` (the generic of `IdentityUser<T>` is `int` in my case). Looking a bit into `UserManager<T>` one can see that said method uses `GetUserId` and that itself tries to get the ID by using `FindFirstValue(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType)` on the given `ClaimsPrincipal`.

The problem is (as I can see by looking in to the Claims myself) that the Claim with the name of `UserIdClaimType` contains the `IdentityUser<T>.UserName` and `UserNameClaimType` contains the `IdentityUser<T>.Id`, so it's exactly the wrong way around.

Am I missing to configure something or is this a bug in ASP.NET Core/Identity 5.0?

In case that it's relevant, this is the code in the `ConfigureServices` regarding Identity and Authentication:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyUserContext>((services, options) =>
{
    string usersFilePath = [...];
    options.UseSqlite($"Filename={usersFilePath}");
});

services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser<int>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyUserContext>();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {
            // [...]
        };
    })
    .AddApplicationCookie();
```

Comment: ` [...] is not valid value for Int32. (Parameter: 'value')` the error means the value you are inserting is not a valid integer value,you need to check the  type of the value.

Comment: It was only a symptom of the problem. What the cause of the problem was and how it was fixed, can be seen in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found what was causing the problem:

On logging in to my web service I create a JWT security token that the user can use on subsequent calls. The code for this is as follows:

```
var parameters = options.TokenValidationParameters;

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Issuer = parameters.ValidIssuer,
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
        new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.Id.ToString()),
        new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), // will ensure JWT token is unique every time
    }),
    Audience = parameters.ValidAudience,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(ExpirationSeconds),
    NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
    //IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow, // not necessary, will be set automatically
    SigningCredentials = parameters.GetSigningCredentials(),
};

var tokenHandler = options.GetJwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtToken = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);
string accessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtToken);
```

The cause for the described problem are the first two claims and how the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` processes them. As I use the default `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` its property `MapInboundClaims` is set to `true`. So on requests done with the resulting JWT some JWT claims will automatically get mapped to claims registered in the XML SOAP or Microsofts schemas. The mapping can be found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/a22c4f474b806c7c90f6dd9b5fd371fd55db51d4/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs).

As one can see there `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub` and `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId` will get mapped to `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` and `JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName` to `ClaimTypes.Name`. So if I want to get this to work out of the box, without doing any additional configurations, all I have to do is the claims as follows instead:

```
new Claim[]
{
    new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id.ToString()), // Id now here
    new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName), // UserName now here
    // [...]
}
```